# PowerBI query doesn't work with date filter

Tags: if-statement, filter, powerbi, dax, slicers

I have this DAX:

```
Earned Daily =
VAR d = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'P6 Update'[Date] )
RETURN
IF (
    'Data for Pivot'[Date] <= d
        && 'Data for Pivot'[Act Rem] = "Actual Units"
        && 'Data for Pivot'[Type] = "Current",
    'Data for Pivot'[Value],
    0
)
```

`'P6 Update'[Date]` is attached to a Slicer (single select date dropdown).

I see that the date is being correctly set but when I try to use the date to filter it doesn't work.

If I do this:

```
Earned Daily =
IF (
    'Data for Pivot'[Date] <= DATE ( 2018, 4, 19 )
        && 'Data for Pivot'[Act Rem] = "Actual Units"
        && 'Data for Pivot'[Type] = "Current",
    'Data for Pivot'[Value],
    0
)
```

The data is filtered correctly.

What's the problem with the original code?

**#######**

Note: P6 Update table is created with this code:

```
P6 Update = CALENDAR(MIN('Data for Pivot'[Date]), MAX('Data for Pivot'[Date]))
```

Comment: If you do `RETURN d`, does it give a date? I'd expect this to work if `SELECTEDVALUE` isn't returning a blank.

Comment: If your `P6 Update` table is related to your `Data for Pivot` table, that could also cause problems.

Comment: Yep... I guess this is the problem. They're related.

Comment: If your slicer table is related to your data table then it's filtering to just that date and won't consider any prior dates.

Comment: I mean... they don't have any relationship in the Model... `P6 Update` table have its data populated from `Data for Pivot` table. I wanted to created a table that holds the date range contained in `Data for Pivot` and provide a dropdown to the user so that they can select a single date.

Comment: If the slicer table has no model relationships, that shouldn't be the issue. And if you have exactly one date selected with the slicer, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. I'd have to see the actual PBIX or have some way of reproducing the problem to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Even after doing `P6 Update = CALENDAR(DATE(2018,01,01),Date(2018,12,31))` it still doesn't work. I created a measure called `P6 Update date` with `P6 Update date = SELECTEDVALUE('P6 Update'[Date])` and added a Card to show its value. The card shows the date selected in the slicer but the filter doesn't work. Intriguing.

Comment: Wait a sec... this doesn't look like a measure, but a calculated column. A calculated column **cannot** be responsive to a slicer. They aren't dynamic.

Comment: Nope... it's not a column in the Table... it's a measure. It has the calculator symbol.

Comment: How does it work at all then without having any aggregate functions?

Comment: It's actually not working... :) I just wanted to get the single date selected in the dropdown list slicer and use it inside the `IF` statement.

Comment: How does it work with a hardcoded `DATE(2018,4,19)` though? A measure requires aggregates on columns.

Comment: Oh... I misunderstood your question: `Earned Daily` is a calculated column.
I guess you nailed it: ***A calculated column cannot be responsive to a slicer. They aren't dynamic.***

Comment: There's your problem. You can't read a slicer selection into a calculated column.

Comment: You know any way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAX formula appears to be a calculated column rather than a measure. Since calculated columns are only evaluated once each time the table is loaded, they cannot be responsive to slicers or dynamic filtering of any sort.

The solution is to write a measure to produce the values you want instead. It would look something like this:

```
Earned Daily =
VAR d = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'P6 Update'[Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data for Pivot'[Value] ),
    'Data for Pivot'[Date] <= d,
    'Data for Pivot'[Act Rem] = "Actual Units",
    'Data for Pivot'[Type] = "Current"
)
```

You might need to make adjustments depending on what context you are trying to use this measure in, but this is the basic approach.

Comment: Yep... the problem now is that it's summing all values instead of showing `Data for Pivot'[Value]` for each single day. Let's say that date 2018-4-15 is selected... it's summing days 13, 14 and 15. I'd like it to just output `Data for Pivot'[Value]` for each day instead of summing.

Comment: I just answered with the one that worked the way I wanted. Thank you very much Alexis for taking the time and providing valuable insight. Now that we discussed this, I see that what you wrote makes a lot of sense: ***A calculated column cannot be responsive to a slicer. They aren't dynamic.***

Comment: Can you shed some light here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56658634/114029 Would it be that because all 3 columns are calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Alexis Olson's answer, I put together this one that does exactly what I want:

```
Earned Daily = 
VAR d = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'P6 Update'[Date] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM('Data for Pivot'[Value] ),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Data for Pivot'),'Data for Pivot'[Date]=MAX('Data for Pivot'[Date])),
    'Data for Pivot'[Date] <= d,
    'Data for Pivot'[Act Rem] = "Actual Units",
    'Data for Pivot'[Type] = "Current"
)
```

> Added FILTER which makes it match Date by Date
>   until `'P6 Update'[Date]` is reached.