# How to divide each row of a calculated column by the total of another calculated column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, division, calculated-columns

I can't get a division correct with this sample data:

```
Calculated column    Another calc. column
   48                  207
  257                  370
  518                  138
  489                  354
  837                  478
1,005                  648
1,021                2,060
1,463                2,164
2,630                1,818
2,993                2,358
3,354                3,633
4,332                5,234
4,885                6,108
4,514                6,008
4,356                6,888
4,824                7,382
7,082                5,988
7,498                6,059
                     4,865
                     4,192
                     3,816
                     2,851
                     2,768
                     2,093
                     2,207
                       770
                       397
                       149
                       178
                       336
                       167
                       124
                        18
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a new calculated column.

For each row I want to get the value of `Calculated column` and divide it by the Total of `Another calc. column`.

The Total of `Another calc. column` = 82826

This is the desired output in a brand new calculated column, let's call it `% Column`:

```
% Column

0,000579528167484
0,003102890396735
0,006254074807428
.
.
.
```

> **NOTE** - these 3 columns: `Calculated column`, `Another calc. column` and `% Column` are all in the same table and are all **calculated columns**.

I tried lots of formulas but not a single one returned the desired output. :| I guess it's because of the nature of calculated columns or I'm not getting the gist of it.

Is this even possible or I should follow another path using a Measure?

Can you shed some light?

**####### EDIT #######**

I put together a sample file to help debugging this. Here it is:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r7kiIkwgHnI5GUssJ6KlXBAoeDRISEuC

As you see:

- `Earned Daily % HARDCODED` works just fine because `82826` is hardcoded as the denominator.
- `Earned Daily % by StelioK` and `Earned Daily % by Alexis Olson` output the same wrong value for the division when using `SUM` formula.

I'm using the latest Power BI Desktop version if that matters: `Version: 2.70.5494.701 64-bit (June 2019)`

[image]

Comment: Can you share your pbix?

Comment: @RADO: yep... I'll try to clean it and provide a link.

Comment: Great; something else is going on in your model, because DAX here is very simple.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a testing `.pbix`.

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is. Will post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, there is nothing wrong with the calculated columns, and both Alexis and StelioK formulas are correct.

The root problem here is a confusion between calculated columns and measures. You are looking at the results in a conceptually wrong way - through the matrix visual, with several filters active on slicers. If you remove the filters, you will see that the total amount is 140,920, not 82,826. The latter number is the total for the **filtered** data set, not the entire table.

To get this right, you need to understand several fundamental concepts behind Power BI:

- Calculated columns are always static. Once a calculation is
  completed, it can not respond to slicers or other UI controls. It's
  just static data, identical to data in non-calculated columns. DAX
  formulas used to calculate columns are active only when you create
  them, or upon data reload.
- If you want your calculations to respond to slicers etc, they must be measures. It's the only way, no exceptions.
- Avoid calculated columns, they are utterly useless. Power BI is all about measures; I can't think of a single reason for using calculated columns. When you add a column, you are essentially enhancing your source data, because you feel like you are missing something you need for your report. But that need can be much better addressed at the source (database or file you import), or using Power Query, which is designed exactly for this kind of tasks. The best practice is: build your columns at the source, for everything else design measures.
- Another important advice: never drop fields (columns) into visuals directly. Always write a DAX measure, and then use it. Relying on Power BI auto-aggregations is a very bad practice.

Comment: Yep... I'm very new to Power BI stuff and just learning by doing. Suffering now... :) but getting to understand it one piece at a time. Your valuable advice will for sure shape my understanding from now on. Thanks for taking the time to analyze and respond. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You welcome. I would highly recommend you to read at least one good book - it will save you a lot of suffering. There are several new concepts behind this system (like filter context, data lineage, filter propagation, etc), and unless you learn them properly, you'll have hard times understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the following DAX:

```
% Column =
VAR TotalSum =
    SUM ( 'Table'[Another Calc column] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( 'Table'[Calc Column] ) ),
        CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Calc Column] ), TotalSum ) ),
        0
    )
```

Which yields the following:
[image]

I Hope it helps!!

Comment: Are you sure that the columns you used are `calculated columns`? I mean: your `Calc column` and `Another Calc column` are calculated columns?  I tried your code and I'm getting the same results as before, that is, the percentage are wrong and not the ones you show in your printscreen.

Comment: I'm getting `0.034%` in the 1st row... 48/82826 is not this value.

Comment: The interesting this is that if I do `% Column = 'Table'[Calc Column] \ 82826` it just works. `TotalSum` is not being calculated correclty.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri These are not calculated columns but I don't think that would make a difference. What value are you getting for the 2nd row?

Comment: The 1st row gives `0.00034061879080329264`,  2nd row: `0.0018237297757592963`, 3rd row: `0.0036758444507521987`...

Comment: It's dividing by a value approximately = `141200`. Way above `82826`.

Comment: For some reason, in your case, the total sum results in a value of 140,920.00. I have no idea why, this is a pretty standard pattern. Can you return only the 'TotalSum' VAR in the measure I gave you and see what the value is?

Comment: i.e. % Column =
VAR TotalSum =
    SUM ( 'Table'[Another Calc column] )
RETURN
TotalSum

Comment: Yeah... I did that and believe it or not it returns `82826`. I added it to a card and it shows `82826`. This is intriguing!

Comment: If it helps in debugging... my table has a Date and it is filtering... not sure if it would make a difference. I'm analyzing the Excel workbook from which PBI imports the data.

Comment: wait where are you testing the DAX? in the .pbix?

Comment: Testing the DAX in Power BI Desktop.

Comment: I checked the Excel workbook... there it shows 6158 rows and the SUM of  `Value` column is exactly `82826`. So something is not working in PBI when doing the division. I guess this is because all 3 columns are `calculated columns`. Just wondering...

Comment: this is so weird lol try this % Column =
VAR TotalSum =
    SUM ( 'Table'[Another Calc column] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( 'Table'[Calc Column] ) ),
        'Table'[Calc Column] / TotalSum,
        0
    )

Comment: This last DAX gives the same results from the other. :|

Comment: As I suspect it would, very strange! I don't know what to tell you lol maybe check data types and ensure everything is kosher. Aside from that I can't imagine why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Put together a file to help debugging: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r7kiIkwgHnI5GUssJ6KlXBAoeDRISEuC

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri LOL you gotta watch those filters bud!

Answer (score 2):

For me the following works:

```
DIVIDE( Table1[Calculated column], SUM(Table1[Another calc column]) )
```

If that's not working, I'd need to see a file where you can reproduce the problem.

---

**Edit:** After looking at your file, the total of `82,826` is only true ***with the filters you've selected***.

Note that calculated columns are not dynamic and *cannot* be responsive to filters since they are calculated only when the table is first loaded.

If you need it to be dynamic, then write it as a measure more like this:

```
Earned Daily =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Test data'[Value] ),
        'Test data'[Act Rem] = "Actual Units",
        'Test data'[Type] = "Current"
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Test data'[Value] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Test data' ),
        'Test data'[Act Rem] = "Remaining Units",
        'Test data'[Type] = "PMB"
    )
)
```

Comment: Yeah... selecting all the filters returns `140920` that is the value that was being used as the denominator. Again the filters and the nature of calculated columns. I won't forget this. :-|) I should have selected all of them... it seems obvious once we understand what's happening.